# A real time Spectrum analyser with pyaudio in python on Raspi

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

I am trying to get an fft plot on realtime audio using a USB microphone plugged into my raspi. I want to be able to activate an LED when a certain frequency is detected through the fft plot. I have so far tried to get just a live sound wave to be plotted but I am having trouble. I have followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AShHJdSIxkY&lc=z22efhti3uaff52pv04t1aokgg3rlotuia3kw5mpcsnubk0h00410.1510779722591217

I have tried changing the chunk size to a greater value and a lower value but have had no success.For some reason I get the -9981 error but it takes a long time to print the error. No plot is displayed. I have even tried overclocking my Raspberry Pi to see if that would work but it still doesn't work.

I was wondering if anyone else had tried something like this on their Pi and if it was possible or if I had to do it using a different package other than pyaudio.

Here is my python code:

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




CHUNK = 100000
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = CHANNELS,
    rate = RATE,
    input = True,
    output = True,
    frames_per_buffer = CHUNK,
    start = True
    )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0, 2 * CHUNK, 2)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.random.rand(CHUNK))

ax.set_ylim(0, 255)
ax.set_xlim(0, CHUNK)


while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    data_int = np.array(struct.unpack(str(CHUNK*2) + 'B', data), dtype='b')[::2] + 127
    line.set_ydata(data_int)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: I get the same error running this on a Mac with python 2.7.11.  For what it's worth, if I do the following: (1) set `CHUNK = 1024`, (2) use `output = False` in the call to `p.open()`, and (3) remove all the matplotlib code, the program runs with no errors.

Comment: how would I then display it though?

Comment: Also the error still comes up

Comment: I don't have an RPi, so I can't help much more than that.  That's why I just commented, instead of answering.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your approach, but as an alternative you can have a look at those examples of mine: [plot_input.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/plot_input.py) and [spectrogram.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/spectrogram.py).

Comment: I don't know if it's because I'm trying it on a raspberry pi though and the raspberry pi won't have as good computing power, so maybe it can't handle the amount of data coming in.

Comment: This issue also posted at [RaspberriPi stack exchange.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75920/a-real-time-spectrum-analyser-with-pyaudio-in-python-on-raspi)

Answer (score 0):

To display add:
`plt.show(block=False)`
after
`ax.set_xlim(0, CHUNK)`

But with rpi you have to configure your usb sound card as default card